# Is there any chance for android system can automatically clear app's data include database while update app from playstore?

Tags: android, sqlite, memory-leaks, updates, heap-memory

I'm using local database in my app. When i update the app from play store it clears all the existing data (which includes database data).  I am facing this issue only in one type of device( Nokia 5 and api level is 27 ) while in other devices/api version it is working as expected.

**Note : During update, memory available in the device was very minimal.**

Once I free up some memory. It works as expected in the same device where i faced problem.

Memory issue is the cause for clear existing data?

Comment: I'm actually looking into a similar problem, but I'm not able to reproduce it whenever I want to. The app data just got cleared (all files and database), and it happened for a few times for Android 8/9 devices. However, I eliminated app update for the root cause, because the last app update time and the new file creation time are hours away. What I am also sure is that only the storage is affected, because it doesn't ask again for any permissions I previously granted.

Comment: Are you using Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.Android for your development?

Comment: @Elvison I can reproduce this issue. When i clear other apps cache and update the newer one its working as expected. After i uninstall app and install the previous version, then i update to newer one. It was clear the app data and working abnormally.

Comment: @Elvison No, i using Android studio.

Comment: Is it because of the different sqlite database versions in the 2 app versions, so that `onUpgrade()` or `onDowngrade()` in `SQLiteOpenHelper` is called?

Comment: Yes updated one has new database version, but unfortunately before app opening  database was cleared. I check the database existence in first page ( launcher activity ). I get `dBfile.isExistence()` is false while updation

Comment: What's your `onUpgrade()` and `onDowngrade()` implementation? They should only be called when you first get writeable database, so your database is already cleared before you do something with it?

Comment: Exactly when launching app it clears data before calling `onUpgrade` or `onDowngrade`, While i monitor by android profiler at the time initialisation native memory take around 300mb ( only in android 8 & 9 ) then it comes to normal such as 10-20 mb range. Do you have any idea about this native memory consumption? and there is any relation with the problem?

Comment: I don't have any clue for the moment, but I think it has nothing to do with memory, because the database is just a plain file in internal storage. I'll try to reproduce your problem with my apps.